# Basic per-vertex Phong Shader has dark spots

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3, lighting

I just started learning OpenGL 3.x and I'm trying to implement a basic ADS/Phong shader in OpenGL 4.4.

[image: Stanford Bunny 1]
[image: Stanford Bunny 2]

Unfortunately I get these weird dark spots underneath [this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/Data/Meshes/bunny.obj) low-poly version of the Stanford Bunny. After using some other models I've come to the conclusion that the culprit cannot be the bunny, so it is probably my shader.

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertex_normal;

out vec3 lightIntensity;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

// Diffuse
// K REFLECTIVITY, L SOURCE INTENSITY
// a AMBIENT, d DIFFUSE, s SPECULAR
struct Light{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 La;
    vec3 Ld;
    vec3 Ls;
};
uniform Light light;

struct Material{
    float shininess;
    vec3 Ka;
    vec3 Kd;
    vec3 Ks;
};
uniform Material material;

void main(){    
    vec4 vertex = vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1.0f);
    vec4 eyeCoords = modelMatrix * vertex;

    vec3 n = normalize(vertex_normal); // Normal
    vec3 s = normalize(light.position - eyeCoords.xyz); // D tw light
    vec3 v = normalize(eyeCoords.xyz);
    vec3 r = reflect(-s, n);
    float sDotN = max(dot(s, n), 0.0);

    vec3 ambient = light.La * material.Ka;
    vec3 diffuse = light.Ld * material.Kd * sDotN;
    vec3 specular = vec3(0.0f);

    if(sDotN > 0.0f){
        specular = light.Ls * material.Ks * pow(max(dot(r, v), 0.0), material.shininess);
    }

    lightIntensity = ambient + diffuse + specular;

    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertex;
}
```

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the normals are computed correctly?

Comment: @smani Just looking at the .obj file again, I can't actually find any lines prefixed vn - I'm using assimp to populate vertex and normal arrays - I'm not sure if it generates the normals since they aren't specified. I'll try finding another model that specifies normals explicitly.

Comment: If the normals are generated automatically, another culprit could be that the polygons are not all orientated the same way, and therefore some normals are oriented incorrectly. To check whether all polygons are oriented the same way, draw with front (or back) face culling and check whether your geometry has holes in it.

Comment: @smani I'm drawing with back face culling and depth testing. Just tried another model that does specify its normals and it is exactly the same story..

Comment: Here is a sphere model with exactly the same problem: http://imgur.com/NIfKVlM.png - I'm using the aiProcess_FlipWindingOrder flag in assimp.

Comment: To check whether it's a normal issue, try changing removing the `max` test from `float sDotN = max(dot(s, n), 0.0);`. If your normals are indeed incorrect, then the dark patches shouldn't be uniformly colored anymore.

Comment: Also note that if your model matrix is not an identity, you have to transform the normal vector also, see i.e. http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_normaltransform.html .

Comment: @smani I think the lack of a normal transform is what's causing the issues here. The problem I've had with multiplying my normal with the modelView matrix is however that when I move the "camera" around, the light moves as well.

Comment: You only need to multiply with the model matrix, not with the modelview matrix. The modelview matrix is the multiplication of the model matrix (i.e. the matrix which moves the model from "model-space" into the world space) and the view matrix (i.e. what you compute via i.e. `gluLookAt`). So `modelviewmat = viewmat * modelmat`.

Comment: @smani I've come up with this (http://hastebin.com/sudumajira.avrasm), but I'm facing the exact same issue: http://i.imgur.com/pJLse9X.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was passing the vertices instead of the normals - I had completely broken my model loader. All is well now and the above code works if the correct uniforms are passed in!